# formatting all values in a structure

Tags: coldfusion

I need to convert all values in a structure (arguments passed into a function) to uppercase.

I wrote the following method, but rather than replace the argument with the formatted one, it is creating a new key to the arguments struct (e.g. for first loop, it creates a key of '1' with the value of arguments[1], next loop creates a new key of '2' with the value of arguments[2] and so on.

Can anyone suggest how I can change the value of each key in the struct?

The code kind of shows what I am trying to do, but let me know if you need more info.

```
public function formatValues(){

        numArgs = structCount(arguments);
        for (i=1; i<=numArgs ; i=i+1){
            arguments[i] = Ucase(arguments[i]);
        }

        return arguments;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function formatValues(){
    for (var i in arguments){
        if( isSimpleValue( arguments[i] ) ){
            arguments[i] = ucase( arguments[i] );
        }
    }
    return arguments;
}
writeDump(formatValues(name="moo",city="baa"));
writeDump(formatValues("moo","baa"));
```

This will work with named arguments and non-named arguments. It also will only modify simple values (strings, numbers, etc) and not complex variables (arrays, structures, objects)

Comment: Scott, that worked perfectly.  To be honest, not exactly sure why this has solved the problem I was having, because assignment seems the same.. but.. I am a happy customer.. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you forgot the parameter?

```
public function formatValues(arguments){

            var numArgs = structCount(arguments);
            for (var i=1; i<=numArgs ; i=i+1)
            {
                arguments[i] = Ucase(arguments[i]);
            }

            return arguments;

    }
```

Comment: Don't forget the var statements for numArgs and i.

Comment: This will throw an error if one of the following conditions occurs:

1. A complex object is passed to formatValues(), such as formatValues( arrayNew() )..
2. You use named arguments such as formatValues( name="Skippy", city="Any Town" )